# My regular expression doesn't match

Tags: regex, perl

```
$a ="SCNSC:                                            SME@companay.isa.come";
$b ="alerts:                                         nek";
$c ="daily-report:                           tasd,dfgd,fgdfg,dfgdf,sdf@dfs.com";

print "matched" if ($a =~ /\w+:\s*\w+@\w+\.\w+/ );
print "matched" if ($b =~ /\w+:\s*\w+[,\w+]{0,}/ );

 print "matched" if ($c =~ /\w+:\s*\w+[,\w+]{0,}/ );
```

its not displaying matched

Comment: Let the silly errors go unedited in light of responses, otherwise the response becomes nonsensical. That's why I rolled back your edit.

Comment: If you had used `use strict; use warnings;` from the beginning in all your code, the problem would have become obvious.  Now you know, so you'll never omit it again. Right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-W` warning option is your friend:

```
$ perl -W sample .pl
Possible unintended interpolation of @companay in string at junk.pl line 1.
Possible unintended interpolation of @dfs in string at junk.pl line 3.
Name "main::companay" used only once: possible typo at junk.pl line 1.
Name "main::dfs" used only once: possible typo at junk.pl line 3.
```

So `$a` and `$c` don't contain the literals `@companay` and `@dfs` they contain an empty (undefined) array interpolated in their place. The expression `{0,}` is equivalent to `*` (meaning zero or more) so let's clean that up and Perl has too much punctuation already so let's drop the unneeded parentheses. This gives us the only match Perl didn't warn us of:

```
print "matched" if $b =~ /\w+:\s*\w+[,\w+]*/ ;
```

which is fine except you probably meant to use grouping parenthesis as the last part of the regexp instead of "zero or more occurences of the character class containing `,` `\w` and `+`. Fixing all this yields:

```
$a ='SCNSC:    SME@companay.isa.come';
$b ='alerts:      nek';
$c ='daily-report:  tasd,dfgd,fgdfg,dfgdf,sdf@dfs.com';

print "matched\n" if $a =~ /\w+:\s*\w+@\w+\.\w+/ ;
print "matched\n" if $b =~ /\w+:\s*\w+(,\w+)*/ ;
print "matched\n" if $c =~ /\w+:\s*\w+(,\w+)*/ ;
```

Which does match all strings. Note that `\w` does not include the character `@` so they match, but maybe not precisely what you wanted.

Comment: answer changed, yes, the regexp was broken too

Answer (score 2):

Always add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your scripts.

It'll bring silly typos and the like to your attention.

Also, avoid using `$a` and `$b` for variable names, as these are especially reserved for the [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) function.